# How can I get the time steps chosen by NDSolve when the Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta" option is given?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve an ODE with `NDSolve` using the `"ExplicitRungeKutta"` method. I need to know exactly which time steps `NDSolve` chooses, i.e., which points in the interval $[tmin, tmax]$ it chooses when it implements the Runge-Kutta method before the interpolation is made). What should I do?

Comment: See [`NDSolveStateData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html), in particular the section
``NDSolve`StateData`` Properties;  also see
[`NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html); other methods can be found in [`NDSolveOverview`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html).

Comment: [`NDSolveUtilities`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html#287875440) can be used for analyzing the solution after the solution has been constructed.

Comment: quick and dirty way: `ClearAll[g];
g[x_?NumericQ] := (Sow[x]; Cos[x]);
ListPlot@Last@
  Last@Reap[NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] g[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30},
     Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"]]`

Answer (score 2):

*To take this off the unanswered list:*

The steps are the abscissae stored in the interpolating function returned by `NDSolve`:

```
ysol = First@
   NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 10}, 
    Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"];

steps = y["Coordinates"] /. ysol // First
(*
  {0., 0.120351, 0.527517, 0.921285, 1.33461, 1.85473, 2.27071, 
   2.75617, 3.20612, 3.69883, 4.24451, 4.86677, 5.51721, 6.0665, 
   6.59295, 7.1106, 7.57393, 8.07059, 8.6011, 9.25316, 9.62658, 10.}
*)
```