# Show list of points in NDSolve

Tags: list-manipulation

When I was solving my ODE system with NDSolve, I obtain

{x[t]->InterpolationFunction[{{1., 126.}},<>][t],y[t]->InterpolationFunction[{{1., 126.}},<>][t]}

How can show a list point?

In particular, I need to know the cordinates of the last point in x[t] and y[t]

Help me, please

Comment: `(x[x[t]] /. sol /. t -> "Domain")[[1, 2]]` and `(y[x[t]] /. sol /. t -> "Domain")[[1, 2]]`.  (First look at `x[t] /. sol /. t -> "Domain"`, which should give you the domain `{{1., 126.}}` shown above. Then `(x[x[t]] /. sol /. t -> "Domain")` gives the x and y values on the first and last points of the domain. Then `...[[1, 2]]` extracts the last point.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48743/how-can-i-get-the-time-steps-chosen-by-ndsolve-when-the-method-explicitrunge,

Comment: Also `Last /@ ({x[t], y[t]} /. sol /. t -> "ValuesOnGrid")` should work.  I'd use a different `NDSolve` call: `{sol} = NDSolve[ode, {x, y}, {t,...}]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael E2, it works!